# Dimensional Analysis

Tags: fluid-mechanics

[image]

I found out that $\Pi_1$ = Q/$\sqrt{gb}$<sup>5</sup> and $\Pi_2$ = H/b. But could a possible dimensionless group also be Q<sup>2</sup>/gb<sup>5</sup>?

Comment: You can raise a dimensionless group to any power and it is still dimensionless. So, to answer the question, the last group is okay. However, it is often considered best to have something you are calculating, like Q, raised to the first power so the first form would be preferred.

Comment: Thanks for the information!

Comment: I don't quite follow, or agree, the first expression as it mixes b (width) and h (head) which are two different measurements.

Answer (score 1):

All three of your proposed dimensionless groups are valid in terms of being dimensionless:

\begin{equation}
{\small 
\left[\frac{Q}{\sqrt{gb^5}}\right] = \frac{\left[Q\right]}{\sqrt{[g][b]^5}} = \frac{L^3T^{-1}}{\sqrt{LT^{-2}L^5}} = \frac{L^3T^{-1}}{\sqrt{L^6T^{-2}}} = \frac{L^3T^{-1}}{L^3T^{-1}} = 1},
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
{\small 
\left[\frac{Q^2}{gb^5}\right] = 1^2 = 1},
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
{\small 
\left[ \frac{H}{b} \right]} = \frac{[H]}{[b]} = \frac{L}{L} = 1.
\end{equation}

Since the question just asks for one of them, it would probably be best to choose the simplest one, which is $H/b$.